# Get the current SearchDepth within the distance cost function of a Vehicle Routing Problem

Tags: or-tools

I'm working on a Vehicle Routing Problem. In my cost function I need to find the current search depth in order to calculate a deferred cost which is dependent on the current length of the intermediate solution. Is this information available via some method? This is my distance cost function:

```
def distance_callback(from_index, to_index):
      """Returns the shortest path distance between the two nodes"""
      from_node = self.routing_manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
      to_node = self.routing_manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
      return self.distance_matrix[from_node][to_node]
```

Answer (score 1):

See discussion on:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/or-tools-discuss/lw_zdalvm6k

The current approach is not possible as the distance callback is called in many places, and is usually cached, especially if written in python.

The original request is to have time dependent demands. It can be modeled with duplicate nodes, in disjunctions, with non overlapping time windows, and different demands.